# p:commandButton is reloading the page to open dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So I have this code:

```
<h:form id="serviceCustomFormForm">
        <p:dialog id="parameterGroupAddDialog" widgetVar="parameterGroupAddDialog" header="#{messages.addParameterGroup}" modal="true" resizable="false">       
            <p:inputText value="#{serviceCustomFormBean.serviceParameterGroup.name}" styleClass="Wid90" />
            <br />
            <br />

            <p:commandButton value="#{messages.save}" styleClass="Fright BlueButton" update="serviceCustomFormForm" actionListener="#{serviceCustomFormBean.addServiceParameterGroup}" oncomplete="PF('parameterGroupAddDialog').hide()" />
            <p:commandButton value="#{messages.cancel}" styleClass="Fright RedButton" oncomplete="PF('parameterGroupAddDialog').hide()"/>
        </p:dialog>

        <div class="Container100">
            <div class="ContainerIndent">
                <p:commandButton value="#{messages.addParameterGroup}" icon="fa fa-plus-circle" styleClass="Fright CyanButton FloatNoneOnMobile" oncomplete="PF('parameterGroupAddDialog').show()" />
                <div class="EmptyBox10 ShowOnMobile"></div>             
            </div>
        </div>
</h:form>
```

When the page is first loaded the @PostConstruct method is called.
When I click the commandButton to open the dialog it's called again. And when I press the Cancel button inside the dialog it's called again.

This behavior does not occur in other parts of the application, and I can't see what I am missing here.

Update: As requested, the Bean code is here:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class ServiceCustomFormBean implements Serializable {

   private ServiceParameterGroup serviceParameterGroup = new ServiceParameterGroup();

   // Other attributes

   @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
       // Reads attributes sent from previous page  
   }

   public void addServiceParameterGroup() {
      // Saves the serviceParameterGroup to database
   }

   // Getters and Setters  
}
```

Comment: I noticed that if I separate the dialog and the commandButton into two different forms the @PostConstruct method is not called on dialog opening but is still called when the cancel button is clicked

Comment: So you contineously talk about a bean, but did not post the code. Please create an [mcve]

Comment: I've also noticed that if I remove the inputText that is inside the dialog, the problem does not occur

Comment: I tried to remove the form from outside the dialog and adding one inside the dialog as suggested, but the behavior persists. As I stated before, for some reason, removing the inputText stops the page reload on dialog opening and the cancel button. But I can't explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time dealing with this problem, I finally found the reason.
The annotation ViewScoped that I was importing in the backing bean was from the package **javax.faces.view**.
The correct one is **javax.faces.bean**.

Thanks for everyone that spend some time trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `Commandbutton` submits the form. You can 
change to this:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" ...onclick="PF('parameterGroupAddDialog').hide()"
```

Type `button` tells primefaces not to submit the form. If the form isn't submitted `oncomplete` is never called. So it's `onclick`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, when I added the type="button" to the Cancel button inside the dialog it stopped submitting the form, but also didn't close the modal.

Comment: @CesarKuehl edited my answer so it closes. if it helped please accept answer and upvote :) By the way some answer under here are plain wrong

Comment: Almost there! Adding the type="button" and the onclick tag did worked on the Cancel button, but the Save button didn't

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following attributes to your 'Add Service' and 'Cancel' commandButton elements: partialSubmit="true" process="@this".
Code like this:

```
<commandButton value="#{messages.addParameterGroup}" ... partialSubmit="true" process="@this" ... />
```

By default, pf commandButtons try to submit the whole form, while in those two cases you just want to call the invoked method without doing a submit. With this, you are saying to primefaces that you don't want to submit it all (partialSubmit=true), and that you just want to process the invocation of the button itself (process=@this).  Maybe that is your problem.

As an additional comment, i don't think getting the label values for the buttons from the bean is a good idea (unless you want to intentionally change the labels dynamically), because you will end up doing excessive requests to the bean. Better try using a messages properties file, as described in here http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try the attributes as soon as I can. As to the label values recomendation, I'm using a resource bundle. 'messages' is not a bean it's the var name I declared on faces-config.xml as follows: <resource-bundle>
<base-name>bundle</base-name>
<var>messages</var>
</resource-bundle>

Comment: Adding the attributes almost solved it. The cancel button works perfectly now, but the save button still tries to reload the page before firing the addServiceParameterGroup method

Comment: Use the same attributes for "save" button: ... partialSubmit="true" process="@this"

Comment: Your page won't reload anymore. After processing, you can try using [messages tag] (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml) to inform the user the result of the processing. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you should put your Dialog outside your main form, at the end of your body or use the **appendTo="@(body)"** param, and then, have another form inside the dialog.